# Readable output for tracking runtime

Tags: bash, time, format

I want to have a proper output style using `/usr/bin/time` and when I try something like

```
/usr/bin/time -f'time=%E' ls > /dev/null
```

the output is

```
time=0:00.05
```

where the **5** says **5 centiseconds**.

If my command/script runs a longer time, the output will be e.g.:

```
time=1:30:05
```

where the **5** says **5 seconds**.

I wanted to have the output written in `man time`:

```
   The format string
       The format is interpreted in the usual printf-like way.  Ordinary characters are directly copied, tab, newline and backslash are escaped using \t, \n and \\,  a
       percent sign is represented by %%, and otherwise % indicates a conversion.  The program time will always add a trailing newline itself.  The conversions follow.
       All of those used by tcsh(1) are supported.

       Time

       %E     Elapsed real time (in [hours:]minutes:seconds).
```

So I don't want to have those confusing centiseconds. The format should be logical and easy readable without using additional scripts like `sed`. When I have a log for several commands, the output should be something like:

```
time=0:00:01
time=3:30:12
time=0:10:01
```

Comment: Okay so you don't want to display centiseconds. What about processes that take less than a second? Do you want them to be recorded as `0:00:00`? That would be an error wouldn't you think?. It seems `/usr/bin/time` picks its output format depending on whether the command runs less than a second or not.

Comment: Yes it should show `0:00:00` for very fast processes. This is way more convenient for the purpose of reading a log file with tracked times. When I read `man time` it says nothing about centiseconds. More options for formatting would be great too.